# Negative lookahead in Ruby with preceding and following matches

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to parse an XML document (specifically a Sublime color theme) and I'm trying to use a negative lookahead to prevent a match that I don't want, but it doesn't appear to be working correctly.

the pattern is as follows:

```
/
<key>name<\/key>
.*?                     # find as little as possible including new lines
<string>(.*?)<\/string> # Match the name of this color Rule
.*?
<dict>
((?!<\/dict>).)*?       # After the second opening <dict>, do not allow a closing </dict>
<key>foreground<\/key>  
.*?
<string>(.*?)<\/string> # Match the hex code for the name found in Match 1.
/mx                     # Treat a newline as a character matched by .
                        # Ignore Whitespace, comments.
```

The string that is being matched is:

```
<dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>**Variable**</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>variable</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
        </dict>
    </dict>

    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Keyword</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>keyword - (source.c keyword.operator | source.c++ keyword.operator | source.objc keyword.operator | source.objc++ keyword.operator), keyword.operator.word</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>**#F92672**</string>
```

The entire string is matched, with `**Variable**` as the first captured group and `**#F92672**` as the second. Ideally, I'd like for the first captured group to be `Keyword` in the second section. I assumed that the presence of the negative lookahead would mean that the first section would not be a part of the match because it would see the `</dict>` and not be able to match.

Does anyone know if I'm doing it wrong and what I can do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do it with Nokogiri:

```
require 'nokogiri'

theme = Nokogiri::XML.fragment(xml)
puts theme.xpath('./dict[1]/key[text()="name"]/following-sibling::string[1]').text
#=> "**Variable**"
puts theme.xpath('.//dict[preceding-sibling::key[1][text()="settings"]]/string').text
#=> "**#F92672**"
```

The first xpath takes the first `dict` and finds the `key` containing "name", then takes the text of the following `string` element.

The second XPath looks for a `dict` immediately after a `key` containing "settings", and retrieves the text of its `string` element.

Note that if you're parsing a full document rather than the given fragment you'll need to make a few changes, such as to change the call to `theme = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)` and remove the leading `.` from the XPath expressions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not too comfortable with xpath and was having trouble with Nokogiri but I'll give it another shot.

Answer (score 0):

The first `dict` with string `**Variable**` and second with `Keyword` have the same structure. And you want to distinct them by a negative lookahead, but that is not possible.

Changes `((?!<\/dict>).)*?` to  `(((?!<\/dict>).)*?)` to debug
and you can see the new group content is

```
result="
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Keyword</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>keyword - (source.c keyword.operator | source.c++ keyword.operator | source.objc keyword.operator | source.objc++ keyword.operator), keyword.operator.word</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            "
```

This satisfy your negative lookahead.

Even if you add more conditions(just using the structure as condition not contents ), because the same structure,`**Variable**` will be always before `**#F92672**`.

So using a xml parser maybe a better choice.